# Ruling on wearing clothes that represents the devil

Tags: practical-islam

I have an asu shirt and pants with a pitchfork representing sun devils on it.

Can I wear this?
If I can't, can I take off the symbols and wear it then?

Answer (score 1):

According to IslamQA wearing a t shirt with the devil logo on it is not haram but it is offensive and that you should watch what you are wearing when in front of Allah. Wear some simple clothes or intricately designed ones without such images. Allah is the All-Knowing and is aware of your clothing style. If you do not have any other clothes to possibly wear then I think it may be your only choice to wear such clothing but if not it is best to abstain from such clothing as it is offensive and also may cause problems with other individuals.